# Set up interface definitions for a category, if methods of the category are called from another class

Tags: objective-c, xcode, categories

Let’s say I have a class   **Alpha** , and a category   **Alpha+morefeatures** with a method  **-(void)foo**. Another class , say **Beta**, should call the method foo.

I like to use the categories for splitting the code into parts, so that Alpha.m will not be a big file.Where should I put the includes & interface description then?

I tried:

file Alpha.h——————————

```
@interface Alpha {
...
}

-(void) foo;
```

file Alpha.m——————————

```
#import „Alpha.h“
```

file Alpha+morefeatures.h --------------

```
#import "Beta.h"

@interface Alpha (morefeatures)
```

file Alpha+morefeatures.m --------------

```
#import Alpha+morefeatures.h

@implementation Alpha (morefeatures)

-(void)foo {
...
}
```

file Beta.h——————————-

```
#import „Alpha.h“
```

**Alpha+morefeatures.h** is not imported anywhere else than in Alpha+morefeatures.m . This compiles ( and runs well) but it gives the following compiler warnings:

“Category is implementing a method which will also be implemented by its primary class”

"Method definition not found"

How can I get rid of the warnings ? I have seen some answers which deal with compiler options - but I assume it is more a syntax problem.

Any advise is appreciated.

Comment: A category is only for adding *new* things not already found in the class.

Comment: Yes, that's the main idea. But Apple explicitly advises to use it  to split large code into parts ( files ) with categories. As long as the class itself calls the category method, there inso issue. The trouble only comes if OTHER classes try to call those methods.

Comment: The key in your statement is "calls". The code you posted "declares" methods in both the class and the extension. That's a problem.

Comment: Take a look at sample code [iSpend](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/iSpend/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003625-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way , finally: All I have to do is to add the interface description into **Alpha.h**

```
@interface Alpha (morefeatures)  
  -(void)foo; 
@end
```

Then import **Alpha.h** in **Beta.h**